# Añadir html a php para estilo

Tags: php, html

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var clickTimes = 0;
    var inicialImage = document.getElementById('inicial');
    var loadingImage = document.getElementById('pensando');
    var ideaImage = document.getElementById('idea');
    var finalImage = document.getElementById('final');
    var btnRandomWord = document.getElementById('randomWordGen');
    var wordOutput = document.getElementById('wordOutput');
    var ocultarCarga = document.getElementById('ocultar_mientras_carga');
    var contenedorWord = document.getElementById('wordOutput');
    var ocultarIdeaMientrasCarga =document.getElementById('ocultar_idea_cuando_carga');
    
    if(clickTimes == 0){
        ideaImage.classList.remove('visible');
        inicialImage.classList.add('visible');
        ocultarCarga.classList.add('visible');
        contenedorWord.classList.remove('visible');
    }

  btnRandomWord.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (clickTimes < 3) {
        ocultarCarga.remove('visible'); // elimina la clase CSS 'visible'
        inicialImage.remove('visible'); // elimina la clase CSS 'visible'
        loadingImage.classList.add('visible'); // agrega la clase CSS 'visible'
        
        ideaImage.classList.remove('visible'); // elimina la clase CSS 'visible'
        btnRandomWord.classList.add('invisible'); //elimina boton generar palabra
        contenedorWord.classList.add('visible');

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // método HTTP y URL
      request.open('GET', 'php/randomwordgen.php?clickTimes='+clickTimes);
      request.onload = function () {
        // estado 4 = petición completada y respuesta recibida
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
          // código HTTP 200 = petición exitosa
          if (request.status === 200) {
            // se define un timeout de 2.5 segundos (ms)
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                btnRandomWord.classList.remove('invisible'); //muestra el boton generar palabra
                loadingImage.classList.remove('visible');
                ideaImage.classList.add('visible');
                wordOutput.textContent = request.responseText;
                clickTimes++;
            }, 2000);
          }
        }
      };
      request.send(); // se envía la petición
    } else {
        loadingImage.classList.add('visible');
        ideaImage.classList.remove('visible');
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                
                loadingImage.classList.remove('visible');
                 
                wordOutput.textContent = 'MEJOR REGALALE UN';
                finalImage.classList.add('visible'); // añade la clase CSS 'visible'
            }, 1000);
               
               
                btnRandomWord.classList.add('invisible');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
<?php

if(isset($_GET['clickTimes'])){
 $numero=$_GET['clickTimes']+1;
   $frases = array(
      1 => "paraguas",
      2 => "bata",
      3 => "ordenador",
      4 => "Un Pecho",

    );

   echo $frases[$numero];
}
?>
```

```html
    <div id="final">
        <img src="images/model_new_mini_one.png" alt="final" title="final"/>
       Nuevo mini
    </div>

    <div id="inicial">
        <img src="images/cocinando.gif" alt="inicial" title="inicial"/>
        Click para pensar una idea
    </div>
    
    <div id="idea">
        <img src="images/idea.gif" alt="idea" title="idea"/>
        Tenemos una idea!
    </div>
    
    <div id="pensando">

        <img src="images/hsk.gif" alt="cocinando" title="Cocinando"/>
        <p>Estamos pensado una idea...</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="word">
      <span id="wordOutput"></span>
        <button id="randomWordGen">Generate</button>
    </div>
```

tengo un codigo php con un array, al que le quiero añadir un estilo para editarlo por css. Cómo podria hacerlo?

```html
<?php

if(isset($_GET['clickTimes'])){
 $numero=$_GET['clickTimes']+1;
   $frases = array(
      1 => "Una lavadora",
      2 => "Un movil",
      3 => "Una muñeca",
      4 => "Un Pecho",
      5 => "Una caca",
      6 => "JOSEJUAN",
    );

   echo $frases[$numero];
}
?>
```

```html
Querría añadir un estilo por ejemplo 1=> "<span class="uno">UNA</span>lavadora"
```

Comment: Te falta mucho código para poder reproducir tu problema, pero entiendo lo que te ocurre y lo que quieres hacer, así que ahí tienes mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que lo que quieres es hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (isset($_GET['clickTimes'])) {
  $numero = $_GET['clickTimes'] + 1;
  $frases = [
    1 => [ 'clase' => 'clase1', 'texto' => "Una lavadora" ],
    2 => [ 'clase' => 'clase2', 'texto' => "Un móvil" ],
    3 => [ 'clase' => 'clase1', 'texto' => "Una muñeca" ],
    4 => [ 'clase' => 'clase2', 'texto' => "Un Pecho" ],
    5 => [ 'clase' => 'clase1', 'texto' => "Una caca" ],
    6 => [ 'clase' => 'clase3', 'texto' => "JOSEJUAN" ],
  ];
  /* Enumeración de todos los posibles */
  foreach ($frases as $indice => $datos) {
    echo '<span class="' . htmlspecialchars($datos['clase']) . '">' .
      htmlspecialchars("{$datos['texto']} ($indice)") .
      "</span>\n";
  }
  /* Impresión del elegido */
  if (isset($frases[$numero])) {
    echo '<span class="' . htmlspecialchars($frases[$numero]['clase']) . '">' .
      htmlspecialchars("{$frases[$numero]['texto']} ($numero)") .
      "</span>\n";
  } else {
    echo "No existe el índice para el número '$numero'";
  }
}
```

Simplemente definimos el texto y la clase como dos índices de cada elemento y con eso tienes hecho el trabajo.

Edito: Por cierto, al tener que recrear tu código para hacerlo funcionar, me di cuenta que deberías sustituir `wordOutput.textContent = request.responseText` por `wordOutput.innerHTML = request.responseText` para que el texto devuelto por el PHP se interprete como HTML y las etiquetas enviadas se mantengan en la página y no se conviertan en texto plano.

Para satisfacer el comentario de enviar textos con varias clases:

```
if (isset($_GET['clickTimes'])) {
  $numero = $_GET['clickTimes'] + 1;
  $frases = [
    1 => [ '<span class="clase1">Una lavadora</span>' ],
    2 => [ '<span class="clase1">Un</span> <span class="clase2">Móvil</span>' ],
    3 => [ '<span class="clase3">MINI</span> <span class="clase4">GOLF</span>' ]
  ];
  /* Impresión del elegido */
  if (isset($frases[$numero])) {
    echo $frases[$numero];
  } else {
    echo "No existe el índice para el número '$numero'";
  }
}
```

Comment: Esto es un boton que cuando pulso envia una palabra por JS al html. Asi que  lo unico que quiero hacer es añadirle una clase a ese texto, para que pueda darle estilo por css ¿me explico?, he actualizado el codigo para que lo entiendas mejor.

Comment: Es una edición muy grande, esta noche le echo un vistazo (si no te han resuelto la duda) y edito mi respuesta, pero a primera vista parece que basta con agregarlo a `<span id="wordOutput"></span>` de modo que te quedaría así: `<span id="wordOutput" class="clase_a_editar"></span>`.

Comment: Es que me gustaria que tuvises dos clases o dos etiquetas: <p class="1">Una</p> <span class="2">lavadora</span>

Comment: Entonces mira bien mi ejemplo

Comment: Lo que dices de <span id="wordOutput"></span> de modo que te quedaría así: <span id="wordOutput" class="clase_a_editar"></span> no es lo que busco, por que lo que busco es que cuando muestre una palabra compuesta como MINI GOLF , pues el MINI tenga una clase y GOLF otra....  @OscarGarcia

Comment: He estado probando el código que me has adjunto, pero no funciona o no sé como adaptarlo a lo que tengo hecho.. Cuando hago click en el boton no me aparece nada... no sé dónde puede estar el error entiendo lo que has querido hacer en el código, pero algo falla y no sé que puede ser porque no soy experto en php. Es como si no encontrase o cogiese bien la palabra, porque como ya te digo no muestra ningun error por pantalla.

Comment: ¿Has puesto las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP? ¿Qué mensaje de error te sale cuando lo pruebas? Por cierto, ¿lo estás probando en un servidor que soporta PHP o en el que dijiste en el otro hilo que solo soporta ASP.net?

Comment: Aquí tienes un contenedor c9 con el código funcionando: https://ide.c9.io/oscargarcia/stackoverflow-47958 puedes verlo online en https://stackoverflow-47958-oscargarcia.c9users.io/ Obviamente no se ven las imágenes porque no las tengo, pero pulsa el botón.